# I need to know how to phrase part of a sentence containing the word of

Tags: phrases, word-usage

I'm editing a document that has the following phrase:

<. . . could have garnered the respect, much less the votes, of Southern conservatives.>

I am wondering if this should be reworded to be the following:

<. . . could have garnered the respect of, much less the votes of, Southern conservatives.> [I've changed the placement of the word of.]
Thank you, N. Bowers

Comment: Since the preposition *of* is applicable to both phrases, it is perfectly alright to use it the way you have in your first example, i.e. just once.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is syntactically correct and stylistically acceptable, probably. But it looks better without the unnecessary pair of *of*s.